How to add a horizontal line within a cell without connecting it to adjacent columns

Hi! I want to add a horizontal line within a cell without connecting it to adjacent columns like the image I post. I try to use \cline{2-4} and \cline{5-7} but it fails as the two horizontal lines will connect with each other; however, I want them separated from each other. Could you please give some instructions to implement this? Thank you.

Welcome to tex.sx.

I suggest you (a) load the booktabs package, (b) replace all \cline{m-n} directives with \cmidrule(lr){m-n} directives and, for good measure, (c) replace all \hline directives with \toprule, \midrule, or \bottomrule directives, as appropriate.
I would also align the numbers in columns 2, 3, 5, and 6 on their (implicit) decimal markers. This may be done, e.g., with the help of the siunitx package and its S column type.

\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs} % for \toprule, \midrule, \bottomrule, and \cmidrule macros
\usepackage{siunitx} % for 'S' column type
\sisetup{group-separator={,}, 
         group-minimum-digits=4}
\usepackage{newtx} % optional, for Times Roman clone fonts

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ >{\scshape}c % automatic small-caps in header col.
                 S[table-format=2.0] % 2 integer digits, 0 decimal digits
                 S[table-format=2.0]
                 c
                 S[table-format=6.0]
                 S[table-format=5.0]
                 c }
\toprule
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{retrain times} 
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{\# labeled samples}\\
\cmidrule(lr){2-4} \cmidrule(lr){5-7}
& {w/o \textsuperscript{1}} & {w/ \textsuperscript{2}} & {Improves}
& {w/o} & {w/} & {Improves} \\
\midrule
MamaDroid & 45 & 35 & 22.22\% & 22411 & 14999 & 33.07\%\\
DroidEvolver \\
Drebin & 59 & 13 & 76.79\% & 167005 & 6173 & 96.30\% \\
Drebin-DL \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}


It works! Thanks :)
